# How do I pass a value in my Route to the Controller to be used in the View in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have 2 entities called **Match** and **Roster**.
My Match routes are like this

`http://localhost:8888/app/public/matches` (index)
`http://localhost:8888/app/public/matches/14` (show)

In order to view/create the teams for each specific match I added the routes for the match roster like this:

```
Route::get('/matches/'.'{id}'.'/roster/', [App\Http\Controllers\RosterController::class, 'index']);
```

Now I need that {id} i have in my URL to pass it to the Controller here:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('roster.index');
    }
```

I need that for a couple of things. First I need to do a search on the Roster table filtering by a column with that value, so I can display only the players that belong to that match.

Second, I need to pass it on to the view so I can use it on my store and update forms. I want to add or remove players from the roster from that same index view.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters ... imagine the route callbacks are your controller methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1 You can get the route parameter defined on ur routes via `request()->route('parameter_name')`.

```php
public function index()
{
    // get {id} from the route (/matches/{id}/roster)
    $id = request()->route('id');
}
```

#2 You can pass the data object via using `return view(file_name, object)`

```php
public function index()
{
    // get {id} from the route (/matches/{id}/roster)
    $id = request()->route('id');

    // query what u want to show
    // dunno ur models specific things, so just simple example. 
    $rosters = Roster::where('match_id', '=', $id);

    // return view & data
    return view('roster.index', $rosters);
}
```

#3 It can be done not only index but also others (create, store, edit, update)

In addition, **STRONGLY RECOMMEND** learn Official Tutorial with simple example first.
Like a Blog, Board, etc..
You need to know essentials to build Laravel App.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, I prefer named routes.

```
 Route::get('{bundle}/edit', [BundleController::class, 'edit'])->name('bundle.edit');
```

In controller

```
public function edit(Bundle $bundle): Response
{
    // do your magic here
}
```

You can call the route by,

```
route('bundle.edit', $bundle);
```